# Wide strings Visual Studio 2005 vs 2017?

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I am trying to hook a function of an old game coded in Visual Studio 2005.

The function uses std::wstring, for some reason the function doesn't read it at all since I am using vs 2017.

I would like to know the difference between both wide strings in Visual Studio 2005 and 2017. And how to use Visual Studio 2005 wide string in Visual Studio 2017?

Note: the hook code is working fine in vs 2005.

Thanks in advance, Best regards.

Update #1: A friend sent me the wide string class from his vs 2005 but still it's missing const wchar_t* constructor

```
namespace std {
class wstring {
    void *allocator;
    union  {
        wchar_t buffer[8];
        wchar_t* p_buffer
    } _myData;

    int size;
    int reserved_size;
};
}
```

Comment: `std::wstring` is a part of C-runtime, which obviously has changed since 2005. Have you tried compiling your code with the old C-runtime?

Comment: Yeah and it worked, but I have to compile it using v141 toolset since my project is not just about this hook and there is a lot of functions in the project that needs v141 toolset.

Comment: I don't think this combination is going to work, vs2017 is prepared to use the vs2015 compiler and libraries but not back to 2005. This is an example of why passing c++ objects across DLL boundaries tends not to work out in the long run, the definitions on both sides have to be maintained in step.

Comment: I'm not sure if your hooking method supports this, but if you're only having troubles with `wstring`, you could possibly copy the old `wstring` definition to your project and use it specifically in this hook. Even better would be to compare the two versions and understand their differences; then create a function which knows how to read the string in its entirety.

Comment: Biggest change to `std::wstring` in MSVC is small string optimisation (added) and possibly (I no longer have 2005 installed) copy-on-write (removed) as this is no longer allowed by the standard.  So quite drastic changes to the internal details of `std::wstring`.

Comment: Well then, I will try to reinstall vs 2005 and fetch for the wstring to copy it into my project.

Comment: I have updated the question with vs 2005 wstring class but still trying to code the constructor, if sm1 could help I will be glad for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researchers and a help from some friends. I have achieved what I want which is building the old wstring class of vs 2005 with a constructor for const wchar_t* and use it.

```
class wstring05 {
    public:
        wstring05(const wchar_t* cstr)
        {
            allocator = nullptr;
            reserved_size = size = wcslen(cstr);
            if (size < 8)
                memcpy(buffer, cstr, (size + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t));
            else
                p_buffer = cstr;
        }

    private:

        void *allocator;
        union {
            wchar_t buffer[8];
            const wchar_t* p_buffer;
        };

        int size;
        int reserved_size;
    };
```